# Is use of empty std::optional<string> UB or not?

Tags: c++

The following code:

```
    std::optional<std::string> so;
    std::cout << so->size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << so.has_value();
```

outputs:

```
   0
   0
```

My question is whether its safe to call : `so->size()` on an empty optional. I used clang sanitizer, but it didnt report any UB in above code.

Comment: It's of course undefined the same way `std::string* so=nullptr; so->size();` would be undefined.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili if that is the same as dereferencing null pointer, then why clangs UB sanitizer does not recognize it? https://wandbox.org/permlink/aMv4ZOpXZeH7GgDD It throws UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer on trival cases as in your example, but leaves std::optional as correct if dereferenced while empty.

Comment: @mike It is probably harder to detect with `std::optional` because the dereferenced storage is internal to `std::optional`. For the pointer example, it is easy to statically determine the pointer is `nullptr`. This is one of the first thing a static code analyzer would be programmed to detect. For `std::optional` it is harder to determine if the internal storage contains an initialized object or not, unless you know how the internals of `std::optional` work. A pointer to that storage will always be a valid pointer to *something*. It's hard to know if that something is a `T` or just storage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `operator->` on an empty `std::optional` is Undefined Behavior, regardless of what type `T` is in `std::optional<T>`.

According to cppreference on [`std::optional<T>::operator->`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*) :

> The behavior is undefined if `*this` does not contain a value.

Comment: A solution without undefined behavior is the member function [std::optional::value()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value) which throws a [std::bad_optional_access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/bad_optional_access) if the optional is empty.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the current [C++ working draft](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4868.pdf)

> 20.6.3.6 Observers [optional.observe]

```
constexpr const T* operator->() const;
constexpr T* operator->();
```

Preconditions: *this **contains** a value.

---

Then:

16.3.2.4 Detailed specifications [structure.specifications]

> Preconditions: the conditions that the function assumes to hold
> whenever it is called; violation of any preconditions results in
> undefined behavior.

Thus, it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling the default [`optional` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) (1 in that link), which...

> 1. Constructs an object that does not contain a value.

When you go to [dereference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*)...

> The behavior is undefined if *this does not contain a value.

Which in your case it doesn't. So yes, you have UB.